# Is there a way to store Key in class which I cast from Firebase object?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my database :

```
[x] database
-- > [+] students
-----> [+] -KuGacomJymBwkcc7zlU (pushKey)
-----------> Name - Jon
-----------> Age - 21
```

I have Student.class :

```
String name;
String age;

public Student(String Name, String Age) {
this.name=Name;
this.age=Age;
}
```

I read the information from firebase datasnapshot like this:

```
Student newStudent = DataSnapshot.getValue(Student.class);
```

When I do this I get the name and the age, but my question if there is a way to store the ID (pushKey) on the Student class without adding a String that will hold it and take another field on the firebase database.

Thank you all.

Comment: Unless you are willing to use  a list to hold that value, or you can create a field for the id and set it to null anytime you are writing to the database(that is if the id field is your major concern)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I prefer keeping the keys and the values separate, or otherwise passing the `DataSnapshot`s around. But if you want, you can also extract the key (`DataSnapshot.getKey()`) and set it on a property in your Java class that you `@Exclude`:

```
public class Student {
  @Exclude
  public String key;
  public String name;
  public String age;
}
```

And then:

```
Student newStudent = snapshot.getValue(Student.class);
newStudent.key = snapshot.getKey();
```

Related:

- [How to manage firebase database keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41697156/how-to-manage-firebase-database-keys/41699704#41699704)
- [Obtaining the reference and key in Custom Object Firebase Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38860224/obtaining-the-reference-and-key-in-custom-object-firebase-android)

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not. This is the only way you can achieve this, by storing that pushedKey in a string. The return type of `getKey()` method is String.

```
String pusedhKey = yorRef.getKey();
```

Comment: I have the Key when i store the data. but the question is if i need to store it on the DB as well ? Seems odd

Comment: It depends. If you need that key to be stored, then store it. This means that if that key is needed in other parts of your app, then store that key in a separate filed. Don't store data in your database if it is not needed. If you need that key across the whole app, you can store it in an `Intent` or in `SharedPreferences`.

Comment: I recommend against duplicating the key in a property of the object. While duplication of data is quite normal in the Firebase Database, this nearby value duplication typically points to something that is better done in code.

Comment: Thanks @FrankvanPuffelen!

Answer (score 0):

When working with firebase, I prefer to store my data in a hashmap, so I can keep my model class clean, while also able to keep the key.

So for example, in `onDataChanged(snap:DataSnapshot)`

`MyModel m = snap.getValue(MyModel.class);
myHashMap.put(snap.key, m)`

Btw, `HashMap<String, MyModel> myHashMap;`

(Excuse the quirky formatting, i'm typing from my phone)