# Trying to get key from firebase, instead getting a weird path

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a database structure like this:

```
"users": {
   "school": {
      userId (randomkey) {
         "email": "email@emai.email"
         "provider": "provider"
      }
   }
}
```

I'm using a recycler view where users can add each other to a group. I'm showing the email for the user in the recycler view and that works fine. But the problem is that I need to retrieve the userId key for the email that is clicked on and append that to a List that I then push to firebase. I'm doing all that with this code.

Adapter class

```
    class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements  View.OnClickListener {

    private ItemClickListenerPeopleToAdd itemClickListenerPeopleToAdd;
    public TextView emailLbl;

    public RecyclerViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        emailLbl = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.emailLbl);
    }

    public void setItemClickListenerPeopleToAdd(ItemClickListenerPeopleToAdd itemClickListenerPeopleToAdd) {
        this.itemClickListenerPeopleToAdd = itemClickListenerPeopleToAdd;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        itemClickListenerPeopleToAdd.onClick(v, getAdapterPosition());
    }
}

public class PeopleToAddAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewHolder> {
    private static final String TAG = "Working";
    public ArrayList<String> peopleList = new ArrayList<String>();
    private List<ModelProject> mModelList;

    public PeopleToAddAdapter(List<ModelProject> modelList) {
        mModelList = modelList;
    }

    private Context context;
    private List<PeopleToAdd> mPeopleToAdd;
    public List<PeopleToAdd> mList;


    public PeopleToAddAdapter(Context con, List<PeopleToAdd> list) {
        this.context = con;
        this.mPeopleToAdd = list;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.people_to_add_listview, parent, false);

        return new RecyclerViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {

        final PeopleToAdd listItem = mPeopleToAdd.get(position);
        holder.emailLbl.setText(listItem.getEmail());
        holder.setItemClickListenerPeopleToAdd(new ItemClickListenerPeopleToAdd() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, int position) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Click" + listItem.getEmail(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                peopleList.add(listItem.toString());
                Log.d("value", String.valueOf(peopleList));
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mPeopleToAdd.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView emailLbl;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            emailLbl = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.emailLbl);
        }
    }
}
```

PeopleToAdd

```
public class PeopleToAdd {
private String email;
private String provider;

public PeopleToAdd(String email, String provider) {
    this.email = email;
    this.provider = provider;
}

public PeopleToAdd() {

}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getProvider() {
    return provider;
}

public void setProvider(String provider) {
    this.provider = provider;
}
```

}

Activity class

```
listItems = new ArrayList<>();
    schoolList = new ArrayList<>();

    adapter = new PeopleToAddAdapter(this, listItems);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    mGetSchool = mDatabase.getReference().child("users").child(mCurrentUserId).child("schoolName");

protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    mGetSchool.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            childPath = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            //peopleAddedTxtView.setText(childPath);
            mPeopleToAdd = mDatabase.getReference().child("users").child(childPath);

            mPeopleToAdd.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

                    PeopleToAdd peopleToAdd = dataSnapshot.getValue(PeopleToAdd.class);
                    listItems.add(peopleToAdd);

                    test = dataSnapshot.getKey();
                    Log.d(TAG, test);
                    peopleToAddAdapter = new PeopleToAddAdapter(SetProject.this, listItems);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(peopleToAddAdapter);
                    peopleToAddAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

I'm somehow getting a strange path as the userID
example: "com.appName.Services.PeopleToAdd@ca8f01". How can I get the right userId (the random key generated by firebase). I have it in the "test" String in activity but how can I add that to the List when a user clicks on that user in the reyclerView. I hope you understand me. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A snapshot contains two main things: the key from where the data was loaded, and the value that was loaded. Right now your `onChildAdded` only uses the value, and throws the key away:

```
public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

    PeopleToAdd peopleToAdd = dataSnapshot.getValue(PeopleToAdd.class);
    listItems.add(peopleToAdd);

    test = dataSnapshot.getKey();
    Log.d(TAG, test);
    peopleToAddAdapter = new PeopleToAddAdapter(SetProject.this, listItems);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(peopleToAddAdapter);
    peopleToAddAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

And since you need the key later in your code, you can't retrieve it anymore. The value doesn't contain the key.

One solution is to add the key to you `PeopleToAdd` class. Based on the answer I gave to [Is there a way to store Key in class which I cast from Firebase object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46282759/is-there-a-way-to-store-key-in-class-which-i-cast-from-firebase-object), that could look like this for you:

```
public class PeopleToAdd {
    @Exclude
    public String key;

    private String email;
    private String provider;

    public PeopleToAdd(String email, String provider) {
        this.email = email;
        this.provider = provider;
    }

    public PeopleToAdd() {

    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getProvider() {
        return provider;
    }

    public void setProvider(String provider) {
        this.provider = provider;
    }
}
```

And then modify your `onChildAdded` to set the key on the `PeopleToAdd` it instantiated from the value:

```
public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

    PeopleToAdd peopleToAdd = dataSnapshot.getValue(PeopleToAdd.class);

    peopleToAdd.key = dataSnapshot.getKey();

    listItems.add(peopleToAdd);

    peopleToAddAdapter = new PeopleToAddAdapter(SetProject.this, listItems);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(peopleToAddAdapter);
    peopleToAddAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Now you can get the key of the `PeopleToAdd` from its `key` field.